# How to add more amount in paypal checkout

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, paypal

in my checkout page i have my paypal checkout button with default amount like below. now i want to add more amount with the total amount like "shipping charge" with it.

```html
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            // Set up the transaction
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '500' // default amount -> i have to add more amount to it.
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
                // Call your server to save the transaction
                return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                        'content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        data: [data, details]
                    })
                });
            });
        }

    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Comment: It seems you can add on the line Cart::getTotal() but never do it, It is not the correct way , Change the getTotal function instead to have more clear code, Also please try to do it yourself and if you face any problem ask here, SO does not work this way to write code for you.

Comment: In your Cart::getTotal function just add whatever you want to add like shipping charges, VAT or any other details then on the checkout page shows these as individual entities

Comment: @BlackXero after execute the script i want to send request to paypal add more amount with the default amount. Because I have different shipping methods with different charge. user will choose there shipping methods according to that it will add the charge with the total amount.